Message Queue de-duplication of messages
Is it possible in rabbiqMQ to depublicate messages at a "Message data" level?
For example if I am processing invoices that are sent to my system by calling my API, but that API is spread over multiple web servers which are handling the requests, and then those web servers put the invoice and the invoiceID on a queue to be processed by a worker.
Say each invoice has a unique invoiceID and should only be processed once but sometimes the same invoice will be sent to the API multiple times (and might hit the same API endpoint on a different server each time).
Is it possible to set rabbit MQ to delete any message that has invoiceID the same as any already processed message?
So I'm talking about duplicates that are not "duplicate messages" but messages related to "duplicate things"
I tried googling for answers about this, but I couldn't find anything that was very clear.

No, the server doesn't know about the content data.
The best practice is to implement an idempotent system.
There are some community plugins like https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication#queue-level-deduplication ( I never tried it )
Or you can use the streams https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2021/07/28/rabbitmq-streams-message-deduplication
